# -nographics alternative for Mac OS X when running Unity3d from the command line?

Tags: macos, jenkins, automation, unity-game-engine

I would like to implement CI on a Unity3D project running on a Mac. Jenkins is my preferred CI server, I have looked at the [Unity3dBuilder Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Unity3dBuilder+Plugin) and I'm looking for alternatives to it. To start with, there is no `-nographics` option in Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The [Unity3d -nographics command line option is not available on Mac](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html).
- You have complete control of the arguments you send to Unity3d through the plugin when specifying the "Editor command line arguments".

What are you trying to do exactly ?

*Note*: I am the author of the Unity3DBuilder plugin. So please report any missing feature to the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: My ask, simply put is to set up CI on a headless server and completely automate unity3d builds (I need IOS and android to be built separately, build could be time triggered or code change triggered), then run some tests using the newly built app or apk.

Initial problem that I'm trying to solve is to automate a remote installation including registration of unity3d using preset credentials. But registration seems impossible on a headless server (any machine without GUI for that matter)

Comment: Can't you start Unity from an SSH shell using the appropriate display/xauth directves to have its GUI displayed on your client? Unfortunately Unity makes it a bit hard to do a license registration without a display. I always install my servers manually because of that.

Comment: I'm trying to set it up on a remote build server (headless), I doubt any display directives will work.